# files.list : 'xxx' in parents OR 'yyy' in parents : no results if no rights to either

Tags: google-drive-api

Using API Explorer if I use a query like:

q=('xxx' in parents) or ('yyy' in parents)

...if xxx is not shared with me, I get no results even though yyy is shared with me and contains files.

If I share 'xxx' with myself or remove that part of the query I get results from yyy as expected.

This makes it impossible to use this style of query without knowing for certain that each potential parent folder still exists and is still shared with me.

Answer (score 0):

You might use OR in uppercase?

I think q = '"xxx" in parents OR "yyy" in parents' will do the trick.
I often use this query to search in folder+subfolders and adding an insane amount of "xxx" in parents OR "xxx" in parents OR "xxx" in parents OR "xxx" in parents OR "xxx" in parents OR "xxx" in parents OR  :)

Actually I then do:

q = 'fullText contains "test" AND ("xxx" in parents OR "xxx" in parents OR "xxx" in parents OR "xxx" in parents)'

Comment: Hi Riel, that doesn't help, nor do brackets. If you're using multiple 'xxx' in parents you need to look closely at this because you'll be getting zero results if ANY of the parents are out of your reach. I'd really like to hear from Google on this one, e.g. Eric Koleda.

Comment: Hmm, I need to test this.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug, please file an issue [here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/).

Comment: filed as [Issue 3749](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3749)

Comment: Any news on when this issue is going to be fixed on API v3?